# Can't set proper resolution with a Geforce 520 

Tags: nvidia, 12.04, multiple-monitors

I installed the 12.04 LTS but cannot get my two monitors working.
The latest nvidia-current drivers installed, but i just cant set proper resolution.
My card is a geforce 520 1 DVI 1 VGA.
With the nvidia drivers installed i can set the DVI monitor to 1600x1200 but the VGA no further than 1360x768 (with nvidia-settings).

Without the nvidia driver (using the nouveau) it doesn't work either.
This same issue i had with 11.10 and i had high hopes for 12.04.

Comment: anyone? this problem is really annoying.

Answer (score 0):

This was my solution to a similar problem:
First, I used the nvidia drivers. Second, it's strange, but I changed the frequency of the second monitor (working fine with resolution 1280 x 1024), I saved the configuration, I logged out and logged in, and then, the resolution I was looking for appeared for the main monitor (1680 x 1050).
Hope this can help.